# C# storing Byte[] and retrieving it from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm inserting the `byte[]` file into MySQL BLOB column, but I can not show the image when retrieving. I have one function to store the image as byte[]

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Which I call this way:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile('trend.jpg');
@field = imageToByteArray(img);
```

In PhpMyAdmin it shows this way

[image]

On the other hand, when I try to retrieve the image into a `picturebox`, I receive an error.

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])item["image"];
pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(bytes);

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

> Invalid character in a base-64

Comment: Exactly where do you get the exception?

Comment: `byte[] bytes = (byte[])item["image"];`

Comment: Check what type `item["image"]` actually is

Comment: It returns `System.Byte[]` always.

Comment: Perhaps the strack trace can give you an hit of what the problem is.

Comment: Doesn't solve the immediate problem, but [`[y]ou must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Usually this could mean a couple of broad things. I have run into this problem where the 64 bit encoded string has replaced a '+' symbol with a ' ' this is due to restrictions in transmitting data.

Comment: @theB: Pretty sure that isn't true

Comment: The problem is on the cast. This line `(byte[])item["image"]` is what throws the error. I can't go further because I need to cast the object into an byte[]